# Existence of a weak solution of a stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am currently studying stochastic differential equations and have no glue how to prove existence of a weak solution. For instance, consider
$$
\begin{cases}
dX_t=dB_t+\sqrt{X_t}dt\\
X_0=0
\end{cases}
$$
on a compact interval $[0,T]$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welll, if your only concern is existence, then there are some results that you can use. 
For
$$
X_t = x + \int_0^t D(X_s) dB_s + \int_0^t C(X_s)ds, t  \in \mathbb{R^+}, x \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
where $C,D$ are measurbale, then a weak solution exists if $C$ and $D$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align*}
&|C(x)|^2 + ||D \circ D^{*}(x)|| \le K(1+|x|^2), x \in \mathbb{R}^d \\
&C \circ C^{*}(x) \ge \varepsilon I, x \in \mathbb{R}^d
\end{align*}
$$
for some $K, \varepsilon > 0$ where $I$ is the $d \times d$ identity matrix. 
For a reference see *On existence and stability of weak solutions of multidimensional stochastic differential equations with measurable coefficients* by Rozkosz and Slominski.

In your case, it will reduce to check if $ 1 + |x| \le K(1+x^2)$ for some K and $1 \ge \varepsilon \cdot 1$ for some $\varepsilon >0$. 
These conditions can easily be verified, so a weak solution should exist.

Comment: For the SDE the OP is interested in things are a little bit more complicated, as far as I can see. Since $\sqrt{X_t}$ is defined only for $X_t \geq 0$ you have to prove the existence of a non-negative solution. (In your setting this corresponds this means that the drift coefficient $C$ is not defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$, but only on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.)

Comment: After reading a bit deeper into the material, in this case the existence of a weak solution can be easily deduced from Girsanov's theorem in connection with Novikov's condition.

Comment: @julian Then why not write an answer to your question? Other users might be interested in the question as well

Comment: Dear SonofX what is $D^*$?